# Unable to read Matrix Parameters from a proxied request

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I am sending the below request to my REST api:
http://localhost:8080/accid234/accounts;email=testme@test.com/departmentUse

Rest-api Java Code:

```
@Path("/{accounts}")
public Accounts getDeptAccounts(@PathParam("accounts") PathSegment pathSegment) {

 Map<String, String> matrixParams = pathSegment.getMatrixParameters();

 for (String s: matrixParams.keySet()) {
        System.out.println("***Matrix params Key:" + s + "Value:" + matrixParams.get(s));
    }
}
```

This works fine when the request is sent directly to the end point  mentioned above.

But when the request is wrapped (in `ForwardedHeaderFilter`), I couldn't read the Matrix Params.

Reason I faced this issue:

I am using spring-cloud-netflix-zuul as proxy routing service and it adds proxy headers such as `x-forwarded-host` , `x-forwarded-proto`, `x-forwarded-prefix` etc to the request. Which is same as wrapping the request.

I configured Zuul not to add proxy headers and then Matrix Parameters worked. But I want to find if I can try to fix it in any other way because I am not sure what issues I might land into if I remove the proxy headers.

The question is: **How to deal with Matrix Parameters in a proxied request?**

I tried using Matrix Variables instead of PathSegment but it didn't worked either.

Answer (score 1):

Spring's `ForwardedHeaderFilter` is stripping the semicolons via its use of `UrlPathHelper`.  You can work around this by setting `UrlPathHelper.removeSemicolonContent` to `false`.

You will notice that `ForwardedHeaderFilter.pathHelper` is a private field so you will need to use reflection to access it.